# Valums file uploader giving an "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error

Tags: c#, javascript, file-upload

I want to use [Valums file upload javascript](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). However, when I run the demo or the tests provided by them I get an `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` in Chrome. It doesn't work on firefox either, but it seems to work on Internet Explorer.

The code is too long to post and I don't know where it goes wrong, if you need a part of the code I can add it in.

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<style>     
    body {font-size:13px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; width:700px; margin:100px auto;}
</style>    
</head>
<body>      
<p><a href="http://github.com/valums/file-uploader">Back to project page</a></p>

<p>To upload a file, click on the button below. Drag-and-drop is supported in FF, Chrome.</p>
<p>Progress-bar is supported in FF3.6+, Chrome6+, Safari4+</p>

<div id="file-uploader-demo1">      
    <noscript>          
        <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
        <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
    </noscript>         
</div>

<script src="fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>        
    function createUploader(){            
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            action: 'do-nothing.htm',
            debug: true
        });           
    }

    // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
    // don't wait for the window to load  
    window.onload = createUploader;     
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably nothing wrong with your code, but you're trying to violate the [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). Basically, if your site is `http://aaa.com/`, you cannot make AJAX called to `http://bbb.com/`.

Comment: But if I would implement this, how would I make sure that I don't violate the same origin policy?

Comment: Post your relevant HTML and JS (feel free to skip the c#). It's the only way we're going to be able to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I added the html, the js is too big to put in though